# How to make globalize or internationalize web application with Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to develop web module for multiple countries , 
so i want to know, what is best practice for develop internationalize website, 
i refer so many articles from different different resources, 
but i want to need some suggestions if possible,
like can i use database driven resources rather than .resx file or how to make currencies,date format change in Internationalize website?

Please help me regarding this and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

@Hiren Jasani,

As my person opinion and user experience you should use **.resx** file for each culture that's better why then store culture data into database and if you storing that data into database then you will facing the issue like page loading time is increasing each time, suppose if you want fetch single page data then you should hit first for culture data then goes to other.

Comment: Bro, you can add conditional statement here and one more thing did you ever use / work on the CMS (Content Management System) if no then please see open source project for cms then you should know the logic behind the cms it's will be very easy for you.